# Angularjs - change in scope not reflecting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using ddSlick plugin in my angularjs website. The plugin works fine. But after selecting the option, the scope variable is not updated. It is the same issue in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845362/angularjs-binding-in-scope-not-in-ui). But the answer doesn't work for me.

```
$scope.ddData = []
for(var i in $scope.List){
    var tempData = {}
    tempData.text = $scope.List[i].name
    tempData.value = $scope.List[i].slug
    tempData.imageSrc = $scope.List[i].img + '.png'
    if(i == 0)
        tempData.selected = true
    else
        tempData.selected = false
    $scope.ddData.push(tempData)
}

$('#Dropdown').ddslick({
    data: $scope.ddData,
    width: 350,
    imagePosition: "left",
    selectText: "Select a list",
    onSelected: function (data) {
        $scope.updateSelected(data);
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});

$scope.updateSelected = function(data){
    $scope.Selected = data.selectedData.value
}
```

I have to loop through a variable to get the json data for the dropdown list. Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `ddSlick` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing DOM manipulation form the controller considered as the BAD idea. 
You need to use directive for attaching plugin to perticular DOM. By creating the directive you have good control over that DOM from directive link function & you avoided the `selector` specific code.

To make it more compact and reusable component you could use isolated scope in your directive by adding `scope: {}` in your directive and inside that pass the `data` and `onUpdate`(udpate on change) to be call on updated. So that this component will act as independent and you can easily provide an different with different data.

**Markup**

```
<div dd-slick dd-data="ddData" update-selected="updateSelected(selected)"></div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('ddSlick', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
       ddData: '=',
       updateSelected: '&'
    }
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){ 

      // Watch scope.ddData and attach ddSlick behavior only when it is populated
      scope.$watch('ddData', function(newValue, oldValue) {

          // return if newValue is undefined or same as oldValue
          if (!newValue || newValue === oldValue) return;

          element.ddslick({
            data: scope.ddData,
            width: 350,
            imagePosition: "left",
            selectText: "Select a list",
            onSelected: function (data) {
              scope.updateSelected({selected: data});
              scope.$apply();
            }
        }
      });
    };
})
```

Comment: @PankajParkar yes. It doesn't show the error. But the dropdown list is empty. Is it because the directive is executed before the json manipulation? Can you help with this please? Thanks!

Comment: @PankajParkar That was my edit, but it got rejected during peer review (not sure why). How did it end up here?

Comment: @Digitrance Sorry for that..I didn't get time to accept that..It was really awesome edit..suggested the cleanest way of doing the OP's requirement.Thanks for your precious time & edit.